# Looping through json object from a checkbox loop

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have a json object thats being loaded through a checkbox in an ng-repeat. It lists possible services and I'm trying to get access to the ones that have been checked when I submit the form.

I'm loading the checkbox through:

```
<label style="margin-right:10px" ng-repeat="item in dsServces">
    <input
        type="checkbox"
        name="selectedFruits"
        value="{{item.DefaultServiceID}}"
        ng-model="expense.dsService[item.DefaultServiceName]"
    > {{item.DefaultServiceName}}
</label>
```

I can see the expense is being built by testing with:

```
{{ expense.dsService }}
```

returns (when a couple are selected)

```
{"Email":true,"Backups":true}
```

But I can't work out how to loop through so it says just the service name so I can add them against the customer.

In the back end I have:

```
$scope.expense = {
    tags: []
};
```

And on the submit:

```
 angular.forEach($scope.expense, function(item) {
    console.log(item);
});
```

Which spits out  `Object {Email: true, Backups: true}` but I can't work out to have a loop where it just returns which ever objects are true.

My main aim is to have something like

```
angular.forEach(forloop) {
    //service.item should be like 'Email' whatever the item.DefaultServiceName is
    // the loop should be all items that are checked
    addService(service.item);
});
```

Comment: Not clear. create fiddle so that one can help you.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding properly, you want to push the key values of the object into an array. If that is the case, just make a little change to your `forEach()`

Like so:

```
// The first parameter is what you want to loop through
// Second is the iterator, you can separate out the key and values here
// The third is the context, since I put the array we want to push to in here
// we just need to call `this.push()` within the iterator
angular.forEach($scope.expense, function(value, key) {
  this.push(key);
}, $scope.expense.tags);
```

Let me know if this helps.